# adding router service in angular2-todo and errors: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: angular, require

I'm learning angular2 and playing with Colin Eberhardt's tutorial project on github - https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/angular2-todo

To extend from it, I wanted to add http "router" service to it so it can display multiple pages. I cloned it to:
https://github.com/tanchifu/angular2-todo

The modified project builds fine without errors, but the problems I have is the app totally failed to display. And the browser console is showing the following error messages:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined     :3000/app/bootstrap.js:2

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined    angular2-polyfills.js:143
```

I think I am having problems with the systemjs or requirejs includes. So I played with the tsconfig.json, gulpfile.js, but for hours of trying, got very frustrated and gave up. I'd really appreciate if someone can take a look, it must be something in the library includes I messed up.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of the modifications that you made? If there are too many modifications, then I would suggest you make those changes gradually until the bug reappears, then you will know which part of the change is causing your error

Comment: have you add the systemJs in index.html ? either post your code snippet or provide some kind of plnkr by regenerating your error it would be easy to solve your problem than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the value of the `module` attribute within your `tsconfig.json` file from `commonjs` to `system`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "module": "system", // <------------
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Thierry. It did fix the "require is not defined" error message in the browser! Though I'm still not clear when to use system or commonjs for the module option.